# How to initialise Firestore query in initState in flutter

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I am trying to load the data from Firestore, with the help of streambuilder i am getting the respective data and displaying it to the user.

I am passing the value to a variable called 'total' and this total is inialised with 0 and when i try to show this total value it first should the default(0) value and the it takes the value from Firestore.

Below you can see the code

```
            StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserData').doc(getUid()).snapshots(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
                  final DocumentSnapshot? document = snapshot.data;
                  final Map<String, dynamic> documentData = document?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                  accountList = (documentData['accounts'] as List).map((accountList) => accountList as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
                  // getTotalFund(accountList);
                  List amountData=[];
                  double convertAmount;

                  for(int i=0; i<accountList.length;i++){
                    if(accountList[i]['accountType'] == 'Savings' || accountList[i]['accountType'] == 'Cash' ){
                      amountData.add(double.parse(accountList[i]['amountBalance'].replaceAll(',','')));
                    }
                  }
                  convertAmount = amountData.reduce((value, element) => value + element);
                  totalFund = amountFormat.format(convertAmount);

                  return Text(
                    documentData['name'],
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontFamily: "Gilroy SemiBold",
                    ),
                  );
                }),
```

the value total amount i am getting in the Text widget.

```
Text('\u{20B9} ', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff9c9c9c), fontFamily: "Gilroy Medium", fontSize: 23)),
Text(totalFund.toString(),style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: "Gilroy Bold", fontSize: 35)),
```

how to load the totalFund in initState so it will not show the null value.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please add amountFormat code too.

Comment: final amountFormat = NumberFormat("#,##0.0","en_US");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 Future<DocumentSnapshot> getDoc() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserData').doc(getUid());
 }
```

then set FutureBuilder as parent of your body widget like this:

```
FutureBuilder(future: getDoc(),
       builder: (context, snapshot){
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Text("Loading...");
                } else {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Text("error");
                  } else {
                    final DocumentSnapshot? document = snapshot.data;
                    final Map<String, dynamic> documentData =
                        document?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                    accountList = (documentData['accounts'] as List)
                        .map((accountList) => accountList as Map<String, dynamic>)
                        .toList();
                    // getTotalFund(accountList);
                    List amountData = [];
                    double convertAmount;

                    for (int i = 0; i < accountList.length; i++) {
                      if (accountList[i]['accountType'] == 'Savings' ||
                          accountList[i]['accountType'] == 'Cash') {
                        amountData.add(double.parse(
                            accountList[i]['amountBalance'].replaceAll(',', '')));
                      }
                    }
                    convertAmount =
                        amountData.reduce((value, element) => value + element);
                    totalFund = amountFormat.format(convertAmount);

                    return yourBodyWidget;
                  }
          })
```

Comment: I dont want to show the value as 0, when the screen is visible it show show the totalFund value. Moreover i have already initialised the totalFund as '0'

Comment: the reason we use StreamBuilder is that we not allowed to use async function in initState. so you should change the way you handle StreamBuilder state to avoid get null. check out my new update.

Comment: i am getting the same output.  I have updated the screenshot please check.

Comment: now I get your problem, you want call the FirebaseFirestore api once before screen loaded and before user click that button?

Comment: yes, thats my requirement.

Comment: you should update your widget tree and in your body of you screen use FutureBuilder and call FirebaseFirestore api as its future. do you understand that or you want me too update my answer?

Comment: i get it now, restructuring the widget tree will not have any problem, for that i can even use Streambuilder. Thanks for clarifying @eamirho3ein

Comment: I updated my answer again, may help you.